# joomla sef breaks url only on some pages

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, sef, joomla-sef-urls

I have a problem with SEF URLs in Joomla 2.5.7 and component K2 2.5.7. 
Link with SEF turned off looks like:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=262
```

And with SEF on it looks like:

```
index.php/stavebnici
```

which is perfect!

But another page on this site:

```
index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=2424:adamajana
```

looks with SEF on like:

```
index.php/component/k2/itemlist/user/2424-adamajana
```

my question is: Why is the first one stripped that much of the view and option and the other one is like that? Have you ever seen these problems and do you know how to fix them? Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: By any chance is the first one on a menu and the second one not?

Comment: yes, that is the case ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why ?

See George Wilson's comment.

> How to fix it (to have nice SEF urls) ?

In my opinion you can:

- Create a menu item for that specific article.
- Use an extension like sh404SEF.

Comment: thank you for your input! Do you think it would be possible to make the SEF via htaccess file?

Comment: I think it's possible, however it could be long or complex depending on the number of extensions you have installed on your joomla website.

Comment: all i need is to transform all urls starting: index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id={some_varible}-{alias}.html to {some_variable}-{alias}.html

Comment: I can't help you with that, however there are a lot of questions regarding URL rewrites in SO.